# If X is a random variable that only takes the values 0 or 1, does that guarantee X is an indicator function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we suppose that $X$ is a random variable that takes only the values $0$ or $1$. Must $X$ be an indicator function?

Would it be accurate to say that the answer to this question be a yes since this implies that we can map elements in the sample space to either $1$ or $0$?

Comment: What do you think it would be indicating? The membership in a particular Borel set?

Comment: I just started learning statistics and as far as I understand, isn't the variable simply is associated with the occurrence of a certain event in our sample space?

Comment: Correct, see @Alan's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the definition of an indicator function is a function that takes the value of $1$ on the set that it is indicating for and $0$ otherwise.   So this would be an indicator function on the set $X^{-1}(\{1\})$, or as the comment says in statistics terms, $[X=1]$.

Comment: What if, for example X represented the number of tails we get when we toss a 2-sided coin? Would X still be an indicator variable in that case?

Comment: Yes. The number of tails (for a single toss of the coin)  is either $0$ or $1$

Comment: Note.  The event $X^{-1}(\{1\})$ probably should be written as $[X=1]$ or something.  A "beginner in statistics" may not be assuming the Kolmogorov model.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks,  I only have a minimal statistics background so I naturally don't think that way. Added